# Dynamic title in php

Tags: php, function, variables, title

I am Trying to get the page title (`<title>bla..bla..bla..</title>`) to be changable in php with a multi-file layout like so:
Functions.php is included into index.php, then get_header() is called from functions.php to include the page header.php the title tag is inside the header file. I would like to be able to set the title from index.php how can i do this?

For examle this is what i have tried:
Index.php:

```
<? require_once('includes/functions.php'); global $t; $t = '/home/s0urc3'; get_header();?>

<div id="main">

    <h2><a href="NEEDED" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to NEEDED">NEEDED</a></h2>


    <p class="postmeta"><a href="<?php page_url(yes)?>" class="readmore">Permalink</a> | <span class="date">Revision Date</span></p>

        <p>CONTENT AND CRAP</p>

    <!-- main ends -->  
</div>
<?php /*test*/echo($title);/*test*/ get_footer();?>
```

Header.php:

```
<?php //include('functions.php')?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<? title('$t')?>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<?php get_theme_css()?>
</head>

<body>
<!-- wrap starts here -->
<div id="wrap">

    <!--header -->
    <div id="header">               
        <h1 id="logo-text"><a href="<?php echo (HOME)?>"><img src="<?php get_url('images/Logo.png')?>" alt="S0URC3"><!-- S0URC3 --></a></h1></div>  

<p id="intro">
        Just another poorly coded website!
        </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <!-- <div id="navi"><div id="menu" class="fixed"> -->
            <ul class="">
            <li class=""><a href="http://s0urc3.ismywebsite.com">Home</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="http://blog.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com">Blog</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="http://forums.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com">Forums</a></li>
            <li class=""> <a href="mailto:ellisgeek@gmail.com?subject=Comments">Comments</a></li>
            <!--<li class="">Clans</li>-->
            <li class=""><a href="http://astro.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com">-astro-</a></li>
            <!--<li class=""><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Resources</a></li>         
            <li class=""><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>         
            <li class=""><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>-->          
        </ul><!-- </div></div> -->

        </div>                  
    <!--header ends-->                  
    </div>

    <!-- content-wrap starts -->
    <div id="content-wrap">
```

Functions.php:

```
<?php
require_once('constants.php');
  //===============//
 //Start Functions//
//===============//

//Gets a file from the domain http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/
function get_url($file)
{
echo (FILE_ROOT . $file);
}

//gets the url of the theme
function get_theme_css() {echo('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . FILE_ROOT . 'colourise/style.css" type="text/css" />');}

function get_header() {require_once('includes/header.php');}

function get_footer() {require_once('includes/footer.php');}

//Gets the URL of the current page
function page_url($p)
{
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? ''
        : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s"
        : "";
    $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s;
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? ""
        : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
        if ($p == 'yes')
  echo ($protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
else
    return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
function strleft($s1, $s2)
{
    return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2));
}

//gets the year
function cur_year() {echo (YEAR);}

function ads($code) {echo('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://links.ismywebsite.com?i='. $code .'"></script>');}

function title($title)
{echo('<title>Index Of: '.$title.'</title>');}
  //=============//
 //End Functions//
//=============//
?>
```

P.S. I only am including functions once all functions are available in the header and footer when functions.php is called in index.php

Comment: Variable scope? try `global $t` before you call `title()`. Plus you `echo $title` in `index.php`, where are you declaring `$title` at?

Comment: sorry that echo is for testing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the file `header.php` is being included from within a function, so it does not have access to the global variable `$t`.  You will need to do one of the following:

### In `functions.php`:

```
function get_header() {
    global $t;
    require_once('includes/header.php');
}
```

### Or, in `header.php`:

```
<?php //include('functions.php')
global $t;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- etc -->
```

That way, the variable you have declared will be available to the function's local variable scope.

Second, you need to call the function with either double quotes or no quotes at all.  Single quotes will not parse a variable.

## Right

- `title($t);`
- `title("$t");`
- `title("{$t}");`

## Wrong

- `title('$t');`

[Here is the PHP Manual Page on the String datatype](http://php.net/language.types.string) -- be sure to check out single quoted strings versus double quoted strings.

## Nitpicky Things:

- You should always use the full opening tags (`<?php`), and not the short open tags (`<?`)
- Your functions, like `title()`, should always return a value, and you can echo that, rather than echoing directly from inside the function.
- The `strleft()` function you implemented, though clever, already exists.  See: [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) <s>Actually, this function does the opposite of what you want; I mis-remembered what it did.  Carry On.</s>  EDIT AGAIN: No, apparently I was right, you pass the optional third parameter as true.  You should generally use functions that already exist because, with certain exceptions, they will be faster.

  - A Notable exception to this rule is [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array-rand)

Comment: the strleft() is part of a function for getting the page url that  got from page online.

Comment: OK, I found the problem, I will update my post in a moment to reflect the new solution.

Comment: @Jason: Two reasons.  First, because `<?` is a generic syntax which is also used in other languages, such as XML; in this case, the short open tag is ambiguous and could lead to errors involving PHP trying (and failing) to parse XML.  Second, because it has to be enabled in php.ini and you cannot always guarantee that it will be, nor can you always be sure you can effect it so; short open tags break portability.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out my self

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
<? title('$t')?>
```

to

```
<? title($t)?>
```

in your code.